# where can I find an application using google could speech to transcribe audio recordings?

Tags: cloud, speech-recognition, speech

I am looking for an application (windows, linux or IOS) using google cloud speech. I have not succed to get some python scripts running (using the API and my own json key generated)

Answer (score 1):

Hey man searching through Google documentation I've found a link that might help you.

This one contains several links to samples in a variety of implementations (which includes Python)
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/samples

Hope it helps